# Laravel 5.5 - Método Validate não existe?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou tendo problemas ao realizar uma validação de dados na versão `5.5`, podem me dizer aonde estou errando?

***Erro:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código do `Controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\PainelAdmin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\tbl_categoria;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation;


    class CategoriaController extends Controller
    {

        private $tblcategoria;

        public function __construct(tbl_categoria $categoria)
        {

            $this->categoria = $categoria;

        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            return view('paineladmin.categoria.insert');
        }

        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {   
            // Obtendo todos os campos do Formulário 
            $dataForm = $request->all(); 

            //Validação de Dados            
            $this->validate($request, $this->categoria->rules);

            // realizando a inserção
            $insert =  $this->categoria->create($dataForm);

            // se inserir vai redirecionar para a pagina de consulta
            if ( $insert ){
                return redirect()->route('categoriaIndex');
            } else { 
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }
```

Aqui está o codigo da Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tbl_categoria extends Model
{
    // campos que podem ser inseridos pelo usuário
    protected $fillable = ['titulo', 'descricao'];

    // protegendo os campos e  a tabela de inserções 
    protected $guarded = ['id_categoria', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
    protected $table = 'tbl_categoria';

    // validando os campos
    public $rules = [
        'titulo'    => 'required|min:3|100',
        'descricao' => 'required|min:3|max:1000',
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na classe `$request` do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) 5.5 que tem o método que precisa que é `validate`, então,

***Mude o seu código:***

```
//Validação de Dados            
$this->validate($request, $this->categoria->rules); // Errado
```

***para esse código:***

```
//Validação de Dados            
$request->validate($this->categoria->rules); // Correto
```

***Código final do método***

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    // Obtendo todos os campos do Formulário 
    $dataForm = $request->all(); 

    //Validação de Dados            
    $request->validate($this->categoria->rules);

    // realizando a inserção
    $insert =  $this->categoria->create($dataForm);

    // se inserir vai redirecionar para a pagina de consulta
    if ( $insert ){
        return redirect()->route('categoriaIndex');
    } else { 
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Além desse **erro** de codificação também no `array` de validação que colocou na classe `tbl_categoria` tem um valor sem dizer qual validação é para ser feita, o número 100 valida o que, **observe**:

```
// validando os campos
public $rules = [
    'titulo'    => 'required|min:3|100',
    'descricao' => 'required|min:3|max:1000',
];
```

ou seja, esqueceu de colocar a validação antes o número 100, qual é a validação que precisa?

***Observação:*** *na documentação* [Writing The Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) *explica bem como seria essa forma, e vale muito dizer que existem os métodos anteriores de validação com uma boa explicação*.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Laravel 5.5 - Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)
- [Writing The Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)

Comment: pior que o erro era aquele mesmo.. Resolvido... Faltou um Max em public rules ficando dessa forma    
       'titulo'    => 'required|min:3|max:100',